# Download link not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am using a link button to down load a file from the server.
 Its is working fine when i am using the full path to the page.

the download link is on the default page.

ie http://mydomain.com/default.aspx 
 but not working when using http://mydomain.com/

and offcourse it is workign in local host not on the server.

the code i am using is

```
   try
        {

            // System.String filename = this.ViewState["ImageName"].ToString();
            string fileName = "filename.pdf";
            // set the http content type to "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM
            Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";

            // initialize the http content-disposition header to
            // indicate a file attachment with the default filename
            // "myFile.txt"
            System.String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\"" + fileName +
               "\"";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);

            // transfer the file byte-by-byte to the response object

            System.IO.FileInfo fileToDownload = new
               System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/UserUploads/") + fileName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.WriteFile(fileToDownload.FullName);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        // file IO errors
        {
            //SupportClass.WriteStackTrace(ex, Console.Error);
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

please help me to resolve this

thanks in advance

Shibin

Comment: Could you define the notion `not working`? Are you getting some error? What happens?

Comment: _Works on my machine_ :)

Comment: no error is coming. page jst post backing.. thats all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/" + fileName );
```

[Check this for more details](http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath)